# Vertically aligned expanding menu item on hover & appearing submenu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a top navigation that by default is shown as small circles without any text. On hover, I would like the circle in question to grow/expand and the text of the menu item to appear, as well as a dropdown menu if applicable. Ideally with an ease-in/out effect. Also, In the current setup, I'm not quite sure where to place the submenu in the HTML..

image 1: [default & on hover appearance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nv5Qv.png)

A few requirements:

- Circles expand from the center
- Submenu appears after parent menu item is done expanding, so with a slight delay

I have a [jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/vanaltena/cp91uoLx/3/), but I'm stuck on how to proceed and get the desired effect. Maybe I'm approaching this from a complete wrong angle. Please help!

```js
$(".nav1").hover(function () {
    $(".item1").stop(true,true).delay(200).show(100);
}, function () {
    $(".item1").stop(true,true).delay(200).hide(0);
});

$(".nav2").hover(function () {
    $(".item2").stop(true,true).delay(200).show(100);
}, function () {
    $(".item2").stop(true,true).delay(200).hide(0);
});
```

```css
.navContainer {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.circleContainer {
 float:left;
    position: relative;
    width: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 50px; /* = width for a 1:1 aspect ratio */
    margin-right: 10px;
    background: transparent;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #eee;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.circleContent {
 position: absolute;
    height: 100%; /* = 100% - 2*5% padding */
    width: 100%; /* = 100% - 2*5% padding */
    padding: 0%;
}

.circleTable {
 display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.circleTableCell {
 display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 0.75em;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.hide {
  display: ;
}

.item1, .item2 {
  display: none;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="navContainer">

  <div class="circleContainer nav1">
    <div class="circleContent">
      <div class="circleTable">
        <a href="/link1" class="circleTableCell"> 
          <span class="item1">Item 1</span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="circleContainer nav2">
    <div class="circleContent">
      <div class="circleTable">
        <a href="/link1" class="circleTableCell"> 
          <span class="item2">Item 2</span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got you the following, hope it helps.

part1. the for the circle to scale, use the following on hover:

```
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.75);
  transform: scale(1.75);
```

part2. for the sub menu, you need to add them first then show on hover (you can use the same class you are using for the `item1 item2` etc..

You could use js to push away left/right side menu.

```js
$(".nav1").closest('.wraper').hover(function() {
  $(".item1").stop(true, true).delay(200).show(100);
}, function() {
  $(".item1").stop(true, true).delay(200).hide(0);
});

$(".nav2").closest('.wraper').hover(function() {
  $(".item2").stop(true, true).delay(200).show(100);
}, function() {
  $(".item2").stop(true, true).delay(200).hide(0);
});

$(".nav3").closest('.wraper').hover(function() {
  $(".item3").stop(true, true).delay(200).show(100);
}, function() {
  $(".item3").stop(true, true).delay(200).hide(0);
});
```

```css
.navContainer {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  top: 50px;
}

.circleContainer {
  position: relative;
  width: 50px;
  margin: 25px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  /* = width for a 1:1 aspect ratio */
  background: transparent;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #eee;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
  transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
}

.wraper:hover .circleContainer {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.75);
  transform: scale(1.75);
}

.circleContent {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  /* = 100% - 2*5% padding */
  width: 100%;
  /* = 100% - 2*5% padding */
  padding: 0%;
}

.circleTable {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.circleTableCell {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0.75em;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.item1,
.item2,
.item3 {
  display: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.wraper {
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
}

ul {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}

ul ul {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 25px;
  margin-left: 25px;
  padding: 0;
  background: transparent;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="navContainer">
  <div class="wraper">
    <div class="circleContainer nav1">
      <div class="circleContent">
        <div class="circleTable">
          <a href="/link1" class="circleTableCell">
            <span class="item1">Item 1</span>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <ul class="item1">
      <li>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="wraper">
    <div class="circleContainer nav2">
      <div class="circleContent">
        <div class="circleTable">
          <a href="/link1" class="circleTableCell">
            <span class="item2">Item 2</span>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <ul class="item2">
      <li>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="wraper">
    <div class="circleContainer nav3">
      <div class="circleContent">
        <div class="circleTable">
          <a href="/link1" class="circleTableCell">
            <span class="item3">Item 3</span>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <ul class="item3">
      <li>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
 
</div>
```

Comment: That's great stuff @Daniel, thank you for helping out! Is there are a way to keep the space/margin between the circles the same when one is expanding? I.e. when one circle expands, the others "move out of the way"?